# Mysql: Integrity constraint violation: 1052, Column ... is ambiguous - BUT SEEM NOT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Problem with mysql request.
Particularly, a part looking like

```
supplier.name AS supplier_id ,
```

causes 1052 error - 1052 Column 'supplier_id' in order clause is ambiguous', but a code like

```
CONCAT(supplier.name) AS supplier_id ,
```

works fine, no error. Why?

Full working sql:

```
SELECT
supplier_contract.*,
CONCAT('', status.name, '') as status_id ,
CONCAT(supplier.name) AS supplier_id ,
CONCAT(currency.name) AS currency_id ,
CONCAT(incoterms.name) AS incoterms_id
    from supplier_contract
LEFT OUTER JOIN status ON supplier_contract.status_id = status.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier ON supplier_contract.supplier_id = supplier.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN currency ON supplier_contract.currency_id = currency.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN incoterms ON supplier_contract.incoterms_id = incoterms.id
ORDER BY name DESC, supplier_id DESC
LIMIT 0, 26
```

not working sql:

```
SELECT
supplier_contract.*,
CONCAT('', status.name, '') as status_id ,
supplier.name AS supplier_id ,
currency.name AS currency_id ,
incoterms.name AS incoterms_id
    from supplier_contract
LEFT OUTER JOIN status ON supplier_contract.status_id = status.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier ON supplier_contract.supplier_id = supplier.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN currency ON supplier_contract.currency_id = currency.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN incoterms ON supplier_contract.incoterms_id = incoterms.id
ORDER BY name DESC, supplier_id DESC
LIMIT 0, 26
```

error message:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'supplier_id' in order clause is ambiguous' in C:\wamp\www\stream\classes\class.DBMethods.inc:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\stream\classes\class.DBMethods.inc(15): PDO->prepare('SELECT supplier...') #1 C:\wamp\www\stream\classes\class.TableGen.inc(20): DBMethods::selectBySql('SELECT supplier...') #2 C:\wamp\www\stream\classes\class.TableGen.inc(218): TableGen->getRecords() #3 C:\wamp\www\stream\index.php(82): TableGen->viewRecords() #4 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\stream\classes\class.DBMethods.inc on line 15

Comment: use the alias/table name to prefix the particular reference to `supplier_id`

Comment: Simply add the table prefix to all fields in `ORDER BY` clausule

Comment: The column is ambiguous since you have  `supplier_contract.*` which contains `supplier_id` etc. Maybe it's a MySQL bug.

Comment: you have 2 tables with supplier_id. `concat` somehow cleanses it. Use aliases always

Comment: supplier.name AS supplier_id. The alias supplier_id is itself a field of supplier_contract table. So that's why conflict occur between those two fields. Please give a unique alias and try with it.

Comment: The working SQL should be throwing the same error.

Comment: Yonel - thanx. Working now; at least to the degree of not generating errors.
Spencer - it should, but does not.

No aliases (at this point) because the sql generation function takes table (and field) names from class variables.